# Cutting down a length of a PHP string and inserting an ellipses

Tags: php, string, trim, ellipsis

I want to turn a long string like `reallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongfilename` into something like `reallyreallyre...yreallyreally`.

Basically, find the middle of the string and replace everything there until the length of the string is < 30 characters including an ellipses to signify there has been parts of the string replaced.

This is my code where I have tried this:

```
function cutString($input, $maxLen = 30)
{
    if(strlen($input) < $maxLen)
    {
        return $input;
    }

    $midPoint = floor(strlen($input) / 2);
    $startPoint = $midPoint - 1;

    return substr_replace($input, '...', $startPoint, 3);
}
```

It finds the center of the string and replaces a character either side with `.` but the thing is I can't work out how to make it cut it down to 30 characters, or whatever `$maxLen` is.

Hopefully you understand my question, I don't think I did a very good job at explaining it 8)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
if (strlen($input) > $maxLen) {
    $characters = floor($maxLen / 2);
    return substr($input, 0, $characters) . '...' . substr($input, -1 * $characters);
}
```

Comment: That only adds a `...` to the front of the string, so the output is `...reallyreallyreallyreallyreally`.

Comment: Er, it should put the `...` in the middle of the string James, there are two substr calls there.

Comment: I know there are. But if I put that code in my `cutString` function it returns a string with the ellipses at the front of the string.

Comment: But it does not take into account the three characters added by the '...', so with a maxLen of 30, the result string will be 33 characters long. $characters should not be more than floor(($maxLen-3)/2);

Comment: @James P, to put that code into your cutString, you will have to rename either your maxLen or VoteyDisciple's maxLength

Comment: Quite right; I misread that variable name. I've edited to rename `$maxLen`

Comment: Yeah, spotted that a few seconds ago. Thank you for the code, i'll accept your answer when it lets me :)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not use mb_substr, mb_strlen so it dows not work properly on multibyte strings. It also makes the output LONGER if len(input) is close to maxLen.

Comment: Multibyte strings weren't an issue in this particular case. Obviously if you're working on a different problem where they are, you will need to use `mb_` functions. I wouldn't call that "unfortunate" per se.