# Str::limit laravel

Tags: string, laravel, limit

I have a file name examples:

```
4030-2210201884140.jpg
527884197_w640_h640_1ff2cccdbed562cef696d0c7adf41292.jpg
```

need to do to so was:

```
4030-22...1884140.jpg
5278841...df41292.jpg
```

Been looking for a solution but could not find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cutting down a length of a PHP string and inserting an ellipses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076513/cutting-down-a-length-of-a-php-string-and-inserting-an-ellipses)

Answer (score 0):

I have visited the post

[Cutting down a length of a PHP string and inserting an ellipses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076513/cutting-down-a-length-of-a-php-string-and-inserting-an-ellipses)

But sometimes it may **not fit for you** try below function

I have converted your requirement to a function with default arguments:

```
function getFirstLast($string='527884197_w640_h640_1ff2cccdbed562cef696d0c7adf41292.jpg',$orgOnF=7,$orgOnB=-11,$maskedString='.',$maskRepeat=3)
{

    if (strlen($string) <= 21) 
    {
        return $string;
    }
    $firstPartString = mb_substr($string, 0 ,$orgOnF);

    $secondPartString = mb_substr($string,$orgOnB);

    $maskedString = str_repeat($maskedString, $maskRepeat);

    $finalResult = $firstPartString.$maskedString.$secondPartString;

    return $finalResult;

}

echo getFirstLast();
```